# Filter asp.net GridView data according iasp.net Textbox while typing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have completed the most important part of the application and in current stage i am calling the text box event `TextChanged`. But i want to know is there a anyway to do this task like text changing event in asp.net.In other way how can i implement event like `onTextChanging` in asp.net. Any help please..?

Comment: Have you at least googled _asp net ajax textbox changed_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach client-side `keyup` event handler to textbox and do postback from textbox with `__doPostBack` function:

```
var tbPostBackTimeout = null;

function onTextBoxChanging(sender) {
    clearTimeout(tbPostBackTimeout);

    tbPostBackTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        __doPostBack(sender.name, '');
    }, 500);
}
```

Here is used timeout to avoid continuous postbacks during typing text in textbox.

Comment: Little detail please. I know this is a JavaScript code and should be added into asp.net page. Since i am new to asp.net i am little confused. Any help? Anyway thank for your answer

Comment: You can add "onkeyup" attribute to textbox with "onTextBoxChanging(this)" value of it